# How to simplify this Javascript substring slice search function

Tags: javascript, html, django, url

I have a URL like this in an HTML page on an HREF link:

```
<a id="view_server_link" href="{% url 'view_server' serverid=1 %}">
```

Disregard the Django variable in the template. Effectively this produces a plain-text URL in the rendered HTML page like:

```
http://site.domain.com/page/1/
```

And I'm trying to isolate this:

```
http://site.domain.com/page/
```

in a JS variable so that later I can dynamically modify the HREF URL. All of that is working, but my URL reducing/isolating function seems bloated. I was hoping someone here could find a way to simplify it. Again, this WORKS for me.

NOTE: I don't want to assume the /1/ portion is always the number 1.

```
var $view_server_href = $('#view_server_link').attr('href').substring(0, $('#view_server_link').attr('href').slice(0, -1).search(/\/\w*$/) + 1);
```

Comment: It's off topic, but I'd recomend to use `.prop('href')`. It's content is more reliable. It will always contain an absolute URI, whereas the attribute can contain pretty much everything.

Comment: Noted. I read up on it just now and updated my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just want to change `/1/` to just `/` at the end (where `1` could be any series of digits). If so, a simple `.replace(/\/\d+\/$/, '/')` should do it:

```js
var $view_server_href = $('#view_server_link').attr('href').replace(/\/\d+\/$/, '/');
console.log($view_server_href);
```

```html
<a href="http://site.domain.com/page/1/" id="view_server_link">foo</a>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Perfect. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

May try:

```
url=url.split("/");
url.pop();//remove last elem
url=url.join("/");
```

Short (more or less :/ (more accuratly: obfuscated):

```
url=url.split("/").map((e,i,arr)=>i==arr.length-1?undefined:e).join("/");
```

Comment: That answer is very entertaining. Thanks!

Comment: Please close this question trough marking tjs solution as answer ;)